# How to use Json-c parser or any other parser in Eclipse for C programming in Windows

Tags: c, eclipse, parsing, json-c

**I use Eclipse C/C++ developer IDE in Windows 10** I have downloaded json-c parser but I dont know to use it in eclipse for C Programming. I downloaded it from this link https://github.com/json-c/json-c. I have downloaded the Json Editor Plugin from Eclipse Marketplace.  Please help me out. Any parser is fine. Thank you.

Comment: This link should help.. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1070368&goto=1708706&

Comment: Thanks Vinay for the response. That link is so confusing.
I wanted to know whether I have to include any library or any parser files. Sorry I'm not good at this.